# How can I format my x-axis to include time in order from 6pm to 2am?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, time-series

I want to create a scatterplot for Number of Days Late To School Each Month vs. Typical Bedtime from survey data provided by my stats students. However, my x axis "starts" at 12:00am and "ends" at 11:59pm. How can I make the displayed interval be times from 8:00pm to 2:00am so that the bedtimes will be displayed in sequential order?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange. Please add more details: 1. Describe the relevant spreadsheet structure and settings. 2. Add sample data and create a chart using the sample data. 3. Describe the relevant chart settings.